# Show informative message when the modal is focused

Tags: angularjs

```
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username" required>

                <div class="sidetip">
                    <div ng-show="signup.username.$pristine">
                        <span>Choose a Username.</span>
                    </div>
```

I only want to show the "Choose a Username", If the form is pristine AND the input "username" is focused. How can I accomplish that?

The ng-focus seems like I only can apply on the input, and not what I am asking for "When the Input username is active, display this is if form username also is pristine"...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work? 
[Here is a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CxsboQVReabedQD5keuZ?p=preview)

```
<form name='signup' ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    Username:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username" ng-focus="usernameIsFocus=true" ng-blur="usernameIsFocus=false" required />

    <div class="sidetip">
        <div ng-show="signup.username.$pristine && usernameIsFocus">
            <span>Choose a Username. Click outside text field to hide this tip.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

just a side note

```
signup.username.$pristine
```

is not the same as

```
user.username == ''
```

so if you enter text in input username and then delete it, the first will be `false` and the second will be `true`

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.2 has ngBlur and ngFocus directives, in older versions you can create a directive which changes value given variable on focus

```
is-focus="usernameIsFocus"
```

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username" required is-focus="usernameIsFocus">
<div class="sidetip">
  <div ng-show="usernameIsFocus">
      <span>Choose a Username.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

directive

```
app.directive('isFocus', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      isFocus: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      element.on('focus', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.isFocus = true;
        });
      });

      element.on('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.isFocus = false;
        });
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Here a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Xan0rO8FKeOAlFC2MwoO?p=preview